# IndexError: string index out of range ? bagels game

Tags: python

Just like the title, it always showed:

```
IndexError: string index out of range.
```

Could anyone help me to fix it?

```
clues = []
for i in range(len(guess)):
    if guess[i] == secretNum[i]:
        clues.append('Fermi')
    elif guess[i] in secretNum:
        clues.append('Pico')

...

while guessesTaken <= MAX_GUESS:
        guess = ''
        while len(guess) != NUM_DIGITS or not isOnlyDigits(guess):
            print('Guess #%s: ' % (guessesTaken))
            guess = input()
        clues = getClues(guess, secretNum)
        print(clues)
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/qiyin/Downloads/Python37/bagels.py", line 56, in <module>
    clues = getClues(guess, secretNum)
  File "/Users/qiyin/Downloads/Python37/bagels.py", line 20, in getClues
    if guess[i] == secretNum[i]:

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: What is `secretNum`?

Comment: Post that (and all relevant code snippets) in the question body. It's unreadable in comment format.

Comment: The whole order was attached below. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an indentation error in the `getSecretNum` function, it will always give you a secret number of length equals to one, thus the index out of range.

Well in fact there's other few indentation mistakes!
I fixed them for you:

```
import random

NUM_DIGITS = 3
MAX_GUESS = 10


def getSecretNum():
    numbers = list(range(10))
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    secretNum = ''
    for i in range(NUM_DIGITS):
        secretNum += str(numbers[i])
    return secretNum


def getClues(guess, secretNum):
    if guess == secretNum:
        return 'You got it!'

    clues = []
    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if guess[i] == secretNum[i]:
            clues.append('Fermi')
        elif guess[i] in secretNum:
            clues.append('Pico')
    if len(clues) == 0:
        return 'Bagels'
    clues.sort()
    return ' '.join(clues)


def isOnlyDigits(num):
    if num == '':
        return False

    for i in num:
        if i not in '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split():
            return False
    return True


print('I am thinking of a %s-digit number. Try to guess what it is. ' % (NUM_DIGITS))
print('The clues I give are...')
print('When I say:    That mean:')
print(' Bagels        None of the digits is correct.')
print(' Pico          One digits is correct but in the wrong position.')
print(' Fermi         One digits is correct and in the rigit position.')

while True:
    secretNum = getSecretNum()
    print('I have thought up a number. You have %s guesses to get it.' % (MAX_GUESS))

    guessesTaken = 1
    while guessesTaken <= MAX_GUESS:
        guess = ''
        while len(guess) != NUM_DIGITS or not isOnlyDigits(guess):
            print('Guess #%s: ' % (guessesTaken))
            guess = input()
            clues = getClues(guess, secretNum)
            print(clues)
            guessesTaken += 1

        if guess == secretNum:
            break
        if guessesTaken > MAX_GUESS:
            print('You ran out of guess. The answer was %s.' % (secretNum))

    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    if not input().lower().startswith('y'):
        break
```

Comment: Glad that I helped you ! Happy weekend :D

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

NUM_DIGITS = 3
MAX_GUESS = 10

def getSecretNum():
    numbers = list(range(10))
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    secretNum = ''
    for i in range(NUM_DIGITS):
        secretNum += str(numbers[i])
        return secretNum

def getClues(guess, secretNum):
    if guess == secretNum:
        return 'You got it!'

    clues = []
    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if guess[i] == secretNum[i]:
            clues.append('Fermi')
        elif guess[i] in secretNum:
            clues.append('Pico')
    if len(clues) == 0:
        return 'Bagels'
    clues.sort()
    return ' '.join(clues)

def isOnlyDigits(num):
    if num == '':
        return False

    for i in num:
        if i not in '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split():
            return False
    return True

print('I am thinking of a %s-digit number. Try to guess what it is. ' % (NUM_DIGITS))
print('The clues I give are...')
print('When I say:    That mean:')
print(' Bagels        None of the digits is correct.')
print(' Pico          One digits is correct but in the wrong position.')
print(' Fermi         One digits is correct and in the rigit position.')

while True:
    secretNum = getSecretNum()
    print('I have thought up a number. You have %s guesses to get it.' % (MAX_GUESS))

    guessesTaken = 1
    while guessesTaken <= MAX_GUESS:
        guess = ''
        while len(guess) != NUM_DIGITS or not isOnlyDigits(guess):
            print('Guess #%s: ' % (guessesTaken))
            guess = input()

        clues = getClues(guess, secretNum)
        print(clues)

        guessesTaken += 1

        if guess == secretNum:
            break
        if guessesTaken > MAX_GUESS:
            print('You ran out of guess. The answer was %s.' % (secretNum))

    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    if not input().lower().startswith(y):
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was the wrong positioning of the "return" at the end of the getSecretNum() function, which resulted in the number of non-NUM_DIGITS digits in secretNum being set to 1 in total (1 iteration occurred). This led to a gain in the number of users received and the search for a secret number, since they turned out to be of different lengths.

```
    Correctly:

def getSecretNum():
    numbers = list('0123456789')
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    secretNum = ''
    for i in range(NUM_DIGITS):
        secretNum += str(numbers[i])
    return secretNum

    Not correct:
    
def getSecretNum():
    numbers = list('0123456789')
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    secretNum = ''
    for i in range(NUM_DIGITS):
        secretNum += str(numbers[i])
        return secretNum
```